# Populate variable from partial template in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this sort of function in a browser game i'm making :

```
   def sendAllianceInvitationMessage(invited_user, alliance)
      subject = 'Alliance Invitation'
      body = 'You have received an invitation to join the alliance ' +  alliance.name + '.'
      body += ' Please visit the Alliance Menu in order to accept or reject alliance invitations.' 
      current_user.sendMessage(invited_user, subject, body, 'alliance invitation')   
    end
```

I'm really not comfortable with the idea of loading the body in this way. Is it possible to have a partial that receives parameters (like alliance.name in this code), produces the body content and pass es it to a string variable to be used in sendMessage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render a partial and do a view to do that

```
body = render_to_string('send_alliance_invitation_message')
```

You just need pass your args like a view and you get the result in your body object